# How to access Ajax enqeued file to pass to URL for Ajax call

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to access to a custom php file in WP theme directory to pass to an jQuery Ajax call. I have added following code in `function.php` to register the script and PHP file:

```
function add_ajax() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'addproducts', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/addproducts.js', array('jquery'),'',true );
 wp_localize_script('addproducts', 'ajax_custom', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('session.php')));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_ajax' );
```

Now in my JavaScript file I am trying to pass URL like `url: ajaxurl`

```
var request = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: ajaxurl,
```

but I am getting the `ajaxurl is not defined` error:

> addproducts.js?ver=4.9.6:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxurl is not
> defined
> at HTMLAnchorElement. (addproducts.js?ver=4.9.6:6)
> at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=4.9.6:3)
> at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js?ver=4.9.6:3)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code in your functions.php

```
var request = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: ajax_custom.ajaxurl,
```

You need to call ajax_custom as it is the object of your ajax url

There is another option is possible

add_action('wp_head', 'myplugin_ajaxurl');

```
function myplugin_ajaxurl() {

   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           var ajaxurl = "' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '";
         </script>';
}
add_action('init','myplugin_ajaxurl');
```